# pausing main thread execution other than sleep() in C

Tags: c

I need to pause the execution of the main thread with out using sleep statement.
is there any function or status values that shows the alive status of other threads like isalive() in java?

Comment: What OS?  How about WaitForSingleObject() - Windows.  Any blocking OS function call.

Comment: linux.. and include file is pthread.h

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to wait for another thread to do something; you may want to have a look at `pthread_join()`, which will suspend your thread until another thread terminates; alternatively, semaphores (see `sem_init()` and friends) can be used to build pretty much any kind of cross-thread synchronisation structure.

Answer (score 4):

`pause()` often works well; it suspends execution until a signal is received.

Answer (score 2):

Standard C provides no way to pause the main thread, because standard C has no concept of threads.  (That's changing in [C201X](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1547.pdf), but that new version of the standard isn't quite finished, and there are no implementations of it.)

Even `sleep()` (which is a function, not a language-defined statement) is implementation-specific.

So it's not really possible to answer your question without knowing what environment you're using.   Do you have multiple threads?  If so, what threading library are you using?  [Pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)?  [Win32 threads?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684254%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Why does `sleep()` not satisfy your requirements?  (Probably because it pauses all threads, not just the current one.)

(Hint: Whenever you ask "How do I do X without using Y?", tell us *why* you can't use Y.)

Consult the documentation for whatever thread library you're using.  It should provide a function that does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

A extremely simple approach would be using something as simple as `getchar()`.

Other approach could be waiting for a signal with `pthread_cond_wait` (or any other similar function in a different threading API).

Other approach could be sitting on a tight loop and using a semaphore (or something simpler like a global variable value) to wait for the other threads to finish.

Anyway, there are several options. You don't say enough about your problem to tell what's your best choice here.

Comment: Will `getchar()` suspend the current thread or the entire program?  (It probably depends on the implementation.)  And a busy loop is likely to waste CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

[select()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut) is often a good choice.

On Linux, [epoll()](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) is often a good alternative to select().

And every program, "threaded" or not, always has "main thread".  If you're actually using threads, however, look at [pthread_cond_wait().](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal)

Comment: There's no reason to use `epoll` "just because it's there". OP is not trying to handle 100000 clients, just pause execution...